# Send image with other variables to an api request using axios and multer in react js

Tags: reactjs, axios, multer

I'm trying to send data from the front end to the back end which includes an image. To store the image I'm using multer. Before I decided to add images, all data was being sent perfectly to the back end and stored in a mysql database but it won't work now with an image.

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  const handleFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0])
  }

  async function attemptSharePost(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);

    console.log(formData)

    Axios.post("http://localhost:1337/addPost",{
      image: formData,
      description: description,
      userId: userId,
      name: savedName
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }

  <input
              type="file"
              id="file"
              style={{ display: "none" }}
              onChange={handleFile}
            />
```

This is what the api get request looks like with the multer configuration.

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file, db) => {
        db(null, '../public/images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, db) => {
        db(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})

app.post("/addPost", upload.single('image'), (req,res) => {
    const description = req.body.description;
    const image = req.file.image;
    const userId = req.body.userId;
    const name = req.body.name;

    console.log(image)

    connection.query("INSERT INTO posts (description, img, userId, name, likes, comments) VALUES(?,?,?,?, 0, 0)",
    [description, userId, name],
    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({ message: err })
        }

        if(result){
            res.send({ message: result })
        }
    }
    )
})
```

Comment: FormData can't be nested. Try this `Axios.postForm("url", { image: file, description, userId, name: savedName})`